# Error in transforming blank spaces into 0 after pivoting_wider for performing DGEList function in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, zero, edge-list

the df I'm working on originally is a long format table like below:-

| VALUE | Gene_Symbol | Sample_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12253 | BRCA | P1 |
| 42356 | CAMP | P2 |

Then for generating the DGEList, I decided to transform it into a wide format and generated below table:

|  | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 2423 | 46456 | 74564 | 523424 |
| CAMP |  | 42356 |  |  |
| BRCA | 12253 |  | 453 | 658665 |

because some samples may not express a certain gene, hence the console leave it blank when I wide pivot it. When I view() the df, it showed as blank. But when I do summery() it shows as NULL in the console.

Right now, I am trying to use apply() to replace the blank with 0 but with no luck, all values turned into 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values_fill` function in `tidy::pivot_wider` should do the trick:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, 
                     names_from = Sample_ID, 
                     values_from = VALUE, 
                     values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
#   Gene_Symbol    P1    P2
#   <chr>       <int> <int>
# 1 BRCA        12253     0
# 2 CAMP            0 42356
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "VALUE  Gene_Symbol Sample_ID
12253   BRCA    P1
42356   CAMP    P2
", h = T)
```

Generally, you could  replace the values of `NA` in a data frame without `apply` using something like this:

```
df_na <- tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Sample_ID, values_from = VALUE)

#   Gene_Symbol    P1    P2
#   <chr>       <int> <int>
# 1 BRCA        12253    NA
# 2 CAMP           NA 42356

df_na[is.na(df_na)] <- 0

#   Gene_Symbol    P1    P2
#   <chr>       <int> <int>
# 1 BRCA        12253     0
# 2 CAMP            0 42356
```

Comment: @Spybuster Try the `df_na[is.na(df_na)] <- 0` approach in the edit. If you provide sample data using `dput()`, it would help provide more specific assistance

Comment: Try `values_fill = list(value = 0)`? You can certainly share data example if you make some up. Example data does not have to be real data, just something we can recreate your problem with. I made some by translating your table, and the code worked. So there if that doesn’t work on your read data we will need more information to help

Comment: See the following link to see some ideas: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, its probably an issue with your data (ie, an errand blank space making R interpret it as a character or something)